# Как написать в #[ArrayShape([]), что функция возвращает массив с не ограниченным числом параметров

Tags: phpstorm, php8

Как можно указать в

```
#[ArrayShape([
```

что у массива может быть не ограниченное количество элементов? Я гуглил, но нашел только четкое указание элементов с ключами и значениями
[image: Декларирую ArrayShape][image: Вызываю метод с ArrayShape и пытаюсь получить доступ к элементу с не указанным в ArrayShape ключом]

Comment: вам надо тут что-то вроде `@return array<int, Car>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы хотите использовать атрибут не по назначению, суть этого атрибута указана в комментарии к нему:

```
The attribute specifies possible array keys and their types.

Атрибут определяет возможные ключи массива и их типы.
```

Пример:

```
#[ArrayShape(["f" => "int", "string", "x" => "float"])]
```

То есть мы заранее знаем какие ключи у возвращаемого массива и типы данных.

С подробным описанием можно ознакомиться здесь https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-attributes/blob/master/src/ArrayShape.php

**То есть в рамках этого атрибута - невозможно.**